# HTTP GET request to web app hosted on corporate network

Tags: http, python-requests, ntlm-authentication

I am new to HTTP requests and I am trying to send a GET request to the login page of Oracle Apex Developer which is on a private company server.
I think the browser uses cookies which can expire because when I try to access the URL in the browser (substituting the servers IP as host name), then I first get a prompt to enter my company SSO username and password. This works fine and I can then get the page in the browser. I am trying to replicate this in python but nothing is working for me. I have even tried using HttpNtlmAuth but to no avail.
I could not see anything in Chrome network tab to indicate what the browser is doing and I have tried to simulate most of the HTTP headers in my python code (see picture below)

Here is what the browser was doing once I entered my username and password to get the 200 status code:

Any ideas what I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: There is no picture. And what do you mean by "I could not see anything in Chrome network tab"? When you send a request (while the devtools are open already!) you'll see an entry there (unless you have set your filter incorrectly).

Comment: I see my image uploads didn't work, probably as I am a first time poster. The image for python code can be found here: https://freeimage.host/i/dqbY6F and the image for the browser network tab is here: https://freeimage.host/i/dqb7G1

Comment: CherryDT: I said I didn't see anything that indicated clearly how it is getting authorized.

Comment: What is the difference between the successful request in the network tab (status 200) and the two failed ones before (401)? Also, can you look at the _raw_ request (using software like SmartSniff or WireShark or Fiddler) that the browser sends and compare it with the raw request that _you_ send? This will be the easiest way to spot the differences.

Comment: The only difference in the request headers are that the Authorization value has changed. Also, in the one just prior to the successful one, there is an additional RESPONSE header:   'WWW-Authenticate'.

Comment: I am unable to install software on this company laptop so not sure I can use SmartSniff or WireShark, but thanks for suggestion!